# MySQL Create Summary Table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of answers to questions:

```
table questionAnswers:
    user VARCHAR
    question VARCHAR
    answerValue VARCHAR
```

Important: **Users can post multiple answers to questions**

I want to collect how many questions a user has answered into a table:

```
table users
    user VARCHAR
    questionsAnswered INT
```

Important: **Has to ignore multiple answers to the same question**

Is there a single query that can automatically update the `questionsAnswered` column in the `users` table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE users AS u 
SET questionsAnswered = (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT question) 
    FROM questionAnswers AS q 
    WHERE q.user=u.user)
```

This assumes that all the users in `questionsAnswered` already have an entry in `users`. (This will update `users`, but it won't insert any new rows.)